# Where is the color selection for text menus?

Tags: customization, theme

I want to change the color of the *File, Edit* and *View* menus:

[image]

And all the similar menus such as the 3D view menu:

[image]

Where can I find the settings for these text menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the the group *Pulldown* under *User Interface* as *Text*.

[image]